# Dialling a number using voice recognition

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app which takes the number from voice and dials the number.....Below is My Code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
static int check = 1234;
Button speak_btn,Dial_btn;
TextView speechText;
ArrayList<String> results;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

speak_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Speak);

speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SpeechtextView);//Shows the Number to be Dialed

Dial_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_dial);


speak_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
startVoiceRecognitionActivity();    
}
});


  Dial_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+speechText));
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    startActivity(callIntent);


  }
  });

  }

  public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity(){

Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH); 
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say A Phone Number!");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
 startActivityForResult(i, check);
 }

 @Override

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(requestCode==check && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

  results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

 speechText.setText(results.get(0));

}


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }  
 }
```

Problem is...Every time I press Dial Button,It dials with same Number("2637643") always.(Even when I don't speak any number).I don't Understand What is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + speechText));
```

It should be:

```
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + speechText.getText().toString()));
```

The reason you still get a number even when you don't speak is because `"tel:" + speechText` causes the `toString()` method to be called on `speechText`, which is a `TextView`, and that returns a notation for an Object reference, not the text it contains.